# How to make edit and delete POST Request in same page in my ASP.Net MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a beginner in ASP.Net MVC Web Development. And I am stuck at one place where I need to have POST request For EDIT and Delete Requests in the same page.

**Behavior:**

I have a page with many rows shown in tabular format, Now for each row I wanted to have "Delete", "Edit", and "Details" Button. I have done that successfully. But I read that `we should never have a "GET" Request for Deleting and Editing` a resource.

**Issue:**

I know how to make a POST Form using `@Html.BeginForm(....FormMethod.POST,..)`, But I am confused in my case because I have many rows with each row having "Edit" and "Delete".

Below is my Attempt:

**Parent View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Bridge.Models.Resume>
@using Bridge.ViewModels
<table class="table">
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.datetime)
                    </td>
                    @Html.Partial("_TableButtonsPartial", new SmallButtonViewModel
                   {
                       ResumeId = item.ResumeId
                   })
                </tr>
        }
</table>
```

**TableButtonPartial View:**

```
@model Bridge.ViewModels.SmallButtonViewModel
@using Bridge.ViewModels

    <td style="width: 120px;">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            @Html.Partial("_SmallButtonPartial",
                   new SmallButtonViewModel
                   {
                       Action = "Edit",
                       ButtonType = "btn-primary",
                       Glyph = "pencil",
                       Text = "Edit button",
                       ReferralId = Model.ReferralId,
                   })
            @Html.Partial("_SmallButtonPartial",
                  new SmallButtonViewModel
                  {
                      Action = "Details",
                      ButtonType = "btn-success",
                      Glyph = "list",
                      Text = "Detail button",
                      ResumeId = Model.ResumeId,
                  })
            @Html.Partial("_SmallButtonPartial",
                   new SmallButtonViewModel
                   {
                       Action = "Delete",
                       ButtonType = "btn-danger",
                       Glyph = "trash",
                       Text = "Delete button",
                       ResumeId = Model.ResumeId,
                   })
        </div>
</td>
```

**SmallButtonPartial View**

```
@model Bridge.ViewModels.SmallButtonViewModel    
    <a type="button" class="btn @Model.ButtonType btn-sm"
         href="@Url.Action(Model.Action)@Model.ActionParameters">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-@Model.Glyph">
        </span><span class="sr-only">@Model.Text</span>
    </a>
```

**SmallButton ViewModel**

```
public class SmallButtonViewModel
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Glyph { get; set; }
    public string ButtonType { get; set; }
    public int? ResumeId { get; set; }
    public string ActionParameters
    {
        get
        {
            var param = new StringBuilder("?");
            if (ResumeId != null & ResumeId > 0)
                param.Append(string.Format("{0}={1}&", "resumeId", ResumeId));
            return param.ToString().Substring(0, param.Length - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public FileContentResult Details(int? resumeId)
    {
        var temp = _context.Resumes.Where(f => f.ResumeId == resumeId).SingleOrDefault();
        var fileRes = new FileContentResult(temp.Content.ToArray(), temp.ContentType);
        fileRes.FileDownloadName = temp.FileName;

        return fileRes;
    }

// Todo: Need to make it a POST Request
public ActionResult Delete(int? resumeId)
{
    var r = _context.Resumes.Where(c => c.ResumeId == resumeId);
    _context.Resumes.RemoveRange(r);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("ResumeCenter");
}
```

**My Thinking**

- I want to be able to do something like below in **SmallButtonView** :

  `@model Bridge.ViewModels.SmallButtonViewModel
  @Html.BeginForm(..,FormMethod.POST,..) // but I am not sure how to achieve it?`

Comment: Web-browsers only support POST (and GET) for form submissions - they do not support the full range of HTTP verbs that a RESTful web-service client will use. The only way to use other verbs like PUT and DELETE from a web-browser is through `fetch`/`XmlHttpRequest` - which means adding a dependency on JavaScript support.

Comment: You just need a form in each row with a submit button (which you can style to look like your other links if necessary). The form just needs to include the ID of the object as a route value

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Ok sir. I wil try to attempt it, So, I need to change my `SmallButtonView` right?

Comment: Instead of anchor tag, I will have BeginForm and all of that

Comment: You would simply POST to the delete action. If you want to limit the action to only accept POST, add the HttpPostAttribute to the action (add `[HttpPost]` above the method).

Comment: Yes, just `@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", yourController, new { id = ResumeId })) { // add submit button here }`

Comment: I think buttons like that should be attached to an AJAX POST callback instead of full POST submit - the rows edited/deleted in the same page instead of reload entire page. The target `ActionResult` methods just include `id` argument to query DB & make changes.

Comment: Your really over complicating your view here. All you really need is a `DisplayTemplate` for typeof `Resume` so that in the main view all you need is `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thank you, I will try to implement the HTTPPOST stuff first that you have previously suggested. Once that is done. I will try to learn the new suggestion that you have given (DIsplayFor - Template) too.

Comment: @Dai: I am sorry.I have no clue what you commented.

Comment: @TiesonT.: Yes I will add that verb in my controller action, But before that I want to wire my UI From action for all the Edit, and Delete action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would start by making sure the Delete action could only be reached by a POST request, using the HttpPostAttribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int? resumeId)
{
    var r = _context.Resumes.Where(c => c.ResumeId == resumeId);
    _context.Resumes.RemoveRange(r);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("ResumeCenter");
}
```

Once you add that attribute, any attempts to issue a GET request to that action will result in a 404 (Not Found) response.

Then, replace this:

```
@Html.Partial("_SmallButtonPartial",
   new SmallButtonViewModel
   {
       Action = "Delete",
       ButtonType = "btn-danger",
       Glyph = "trash",
       Text = "Delete button",
       ResumeId = Model.ResumeId,
   })
```

with something like:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("delete", "your controller name", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="delete-form" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="ResumeId" value="@Model.ResumeId" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        Delete
    </button>
}
```

You can have as many forms on a page as you like, as long as they are not nested - this generates a form on each row. I added a class here (`delete-form`) that you could use to hook into a jQuery event, if you wanted to handle this via AJAX instead of allowing the form to submit.

Any other actions, like "view" or "edit", would still just be GET requests, which you can leave as anchors, or use forms with the method set to GET (the end result is the same).

Comment: So, I should have HTTPPost for delete only, Edit and Details are fine with GET?

Comment: If you can tell me in one or two lines, Why I should always have delete httppost. I never understood it conceptually.

Comment: The idea behind "we should never have a "GET" Request for Deleting and Editing" is that GET requests should be idempotent, which (put more simply) means nothing should change as a result of making the request. Your Edit and Details are just requests to load either a read-only view (for Details) or to load a form for making changes (for Edit). The Edit view itself would still POST it's form.

Comment: The idea is that I should be able to GET the same resource one time or 1000 times, and the result is the same and nothing changed on the server as a result (ignoring things like logging - the resource itself should not change). When you delete something, you are most certainly changing a resource, and calling the same action again will have different results.

Comment: Understood. :) So when ever I my action is going to make any change in the resource I should make it as HttpPost

Comment: Doubt 2: Why have you used `<input type="hidden" name="Model.ResumeId" />`. Can't I use @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ResumeId)`. Can you kindly tell me the difference?

Comment: The simplest answer is "yes." There's a vast amount of reading material on the "shades of grey" when dealing with idempotence and HTTP, but the general rule is "is it okay for some agent to make this request more than once with the same form values"; if yes, use a GET.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153723/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-tieson-t).